# Non-fullscreen FLVPlayback

Tags: flash, video, fullscreen, playback

I'm building a full-screen demo where I need to simulate a YouTube video. I dragged a video that plays an external .flv file.

It works fine if the stage isn't set to full-screen. But I need to set the stage to full-screen like this:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

The problem is that when the animation reaches the video the screen goes black and the video doesn't play. I already setting an instance name and tried putting the following code on the frame's actions:

```
video.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
```

But it doesn't affect the issue.

Is there anyway to have the stage in full-screen mode and play the video at it's normal size?

Thaks

I'm using Flash CS3 Pro and generating a .exe.

Answer (score 1):

The glitch seems to be caused by having an `flvPlayback` component on the stage, but not on the first frame of a timeline.

The easiest solution is to either have the compnent on the first frame.

Alternatively if that's impractical, then simply putting the component on the first frame of a movie clip seems to work.

Finally placing the `flvPlayback` on stage with script should work as well.

Just remember `video.fullScreenTakeOver = false;` in all cases

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "scaleMode" parameter to "noScale" in the component's parameters?