# Flash projector fullscreen FLV always has black background

Tags: flash, fullscreen, flv, projector

I'm creating a fullscreen projector that has an FLV file on the stage. I successfully got the FLV to appear non full screen by using the answers for the following question:

[Non-fullscreen FLVPlayback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324102/non-fullscreen-flvplayback)

However, the background still goes black just before the FLV comes to the stage.
It runs fine when the projector is not set to fullscreen - background is there along with my close button.

Any way to solve this?

Comment: I found the solution here: http://www.xllusion.net/ed/2008/06/04/flvplayback-takes-over-when-set-to-full-screen/ Had to do a bit of editing, but it totally works!

Answer (score 1):

If you're rendering to HTML, check your CSS.

Otherwise, you may not have set a color property on one of your DisplayObjects

Comment: Thanks JRM - I don't think I'm rendering to HTML. It's a projector.